# How do I find a memory mapped file's name in WinDbg?

Tags: windows, memory, memory-management, windbg

When I look at my process in VMMap, I can see the filenames of memory mapped files. I'm now analysing a memory dump in WinDbg and would like to know the filenames of memory mapped files. How can I find this from WinDbg or a .dmp file?

Comment: Is this managed or native code?

Comment: It is mixed. The code that maps the files is not managed code. It is a native dll.

Answer (score 4):

`!address -f:FileMap` works in live debugging.

You can see the `!address` docs for more details about other flags you can use to refine the output.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, once you manage to obtain the handle to your memory mapped file, you could view some relevant data (including its name) using the `!handle <address> 0xF` command.
If you don't have a specific handle, but just want to view the names of the existing memory mapped files in the process, you could use the following command: `!handle 0 0x4 Section`.
Which should provide you with an output similar to this one:

```
Handle 6bc
  Name          \BaseNamedObjects\NLS_CodePage_862_3_2_0_0
Handle 6cc
  Name          \BaseNamedObjects\MyMap
Handle 794
  Name          \BaseNamedObjects\Cor_Private_IPCBlock_v4_4092
Handle 798
  Name          \BaseNamedObjects\Cor_SxSPublic_IPCBlock_4092
Handle 7cc
  Name          \BaseNamedObjects\ShimSharedMemory
5 handles of type Section
```

If you'd like to view the actual filename, you could issue the `!handle` command in a kernel debugger to view some information about the system objects that correspond to your  File handles.
For example:

```
lkd> !handle 0 0x3 2c4 File

Searching for Process with Cid == 2c4
Searching for handles of type File
PROCESS 89242da0  SessionId: 0  Cid: 02c4    Peb: 7ffdd000  ParentCid: 0b48
    DirBase: 0a640dc0  ObjectTable: e1c361d0  HandleCount:  83.
    Image: ConsoleApplication1.exe

Handle table at e11f6000 with 83 entries in use

000c: Object: 86a74868  GrantedAccess: 00100020 (Inherit) Entry: e11f6018
Object: 86a74868  Type: (89e2a730) File
    ObjectHeader: 86a74850 (old version)
        HandleCount: 1  PointerCount: 1
        Directory Object: 00000000  Name: \Foo\Bar {HarddiskVolume2}

06d0: Object: 8669c4b8  GrantedAccess: 00100083 Entry: e11f6da0
Object: 8669c4b8  Type: (89e2a730) File
    ObjectHeader: 8669c4a0 (old version)
        HandleCount: 1  PointerCount: 1
        Directory Object: 00000000  Name: \wubildr {HarddiskVolume1}

06d4: Object: 86bf1f58  GrantedAccess: 00120089 Entry: e11f6da8
Object: 86bf1f58  Type: (89e2a730) File
    ObjectHeader: 86bf1f40 (old version)
        HandleCount: 1  PointerCount: 1
        Directory Object: 00000000  Name: \WINDOWS\assembly\pubpol6.dat {HarddiskVolume1}

06dc: Object: 892c43e0  GrantedAccess: 00120089 Entry: e11f6db8
Object: 892c43e0  Type: (89e2a730) File
    ObjectHeader: 892c43c8 (old version)
        HandleCount: 1  PointerCount: 1
        Directory Object: 00000000  Name: \WINDOWS\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\index1fe.dat {HarddiskVolume1}

06ec: Object: 892cf1f8  GrantedAccess: 00100001 Entry: e11f6dd8
Object: 892cf1f8  Type: (89e2a730) File
    ObjectHeader: 892cf1e0 (old version)
        HandleCount: 1  PointerCount: 1
```

Comment: You can have a section mapped in without having a handle to the section open.